# android network first request slow but following request much faster

Tags: android, iis, asp.net-web-api, wireshark, android-volley

I have been working on app in both iphone and android version.
I used ASP.net web api on IIS to serve my network requests.
On iphone all network requests are silky smooth and fast, even the server idle for a while, response is still fast.
On the other hand, the network requests from Android ( I choose Volley library ) behave much differently. If I stay idle on Android client for a while ( only about 30 seconds ), the next request will be much slower. But once I started the first requests, all following requests ( has to make within 30 seconds) are just as fast as iphone counter part.

I captured my requests from Android using tcpdump and opened in Wireshark.

Sorry don't know how to make image bigger, please zoom in on your browser...

fast request: ( follow the first request within 30 seconds )

[image: fast request]

slow request ( idle more than 30 seconds then make the first request ):

[image: slow request]

Notice slow request sends request before handshake and has a lot of re-transmission.
Is there a way to make my Volley network request as fast as iphone network request and not slow down after idle for a while? really want to figure out this because the slowness on android could take up to more than 2 seconds and it really a bad user experience.

Please can anyone help or at least give me a direction?

Comment: Are you sure that the phone doesn't disconnect its wifi connection when idle for too long?

Comment: I tested other apps which use internet on the same device, it didn't response as slow as my app. I think wifi doesn't disconnect.

Comment: Perhaps other apps request that the wifi connection stays active? Can you ping your phone from some other machine and verify that it doesn't stop replying while performing the test described in your question?

Comment: I am facing same issue with Jio... did you fix it ? Can you let me know or post the answer pls ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in some phones but i changed:

```
Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext())
```

to:

```
Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024);
Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
Instantiate the RequestQueue with the cache and network.
mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
mRequestQueue.start();
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you did? You "Replaced": Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext())

with:
Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024);
Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
Instantiate the RequestQueue with the cache and network.
mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
mRequestQueue.start();

That original line is still in there

Answer (score 0):

I did encounter the same issue. What I did was to change A records under DNS, TTL from 1800 seconds to 900 seconds.